# clearInterval of a external function not working - Node.JS

Tags: node.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a setInterval function that's been called in another function, and I need to stop it when the proccess is done. I tried to set this setInterval function as a variable and call clearInterval, but the interval keeps running

```
 const createInterval = (visibilityTimeout, startDateTime, message) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const currentDateTime = moment().valueOf();
    const timeDifference = (visibilityTimeout * 1000) - (currentDateTime - startDateTime);
    if (timeDifference >= 600000) {
      return;
    }
    if (timeDifference < 494983) {
      const params = {
        QueueUrl: 'http://localhost:4566/000000000000/test-queue2',
        ReceiptHandle: message.ReceiptHandle,
        VisibilityTimeout: visibilityTimeout,
      };
      sqs.changeMessageVisibility(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) logger.error(err, err.stack);
        else logger.info(data);
      });
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      visibilityTimeout += 300;
    }
  }, 5000);
};

module.exports = async (message) => {
  const startDateTime = moment().valueOf();
  const {
    noteId,
  } = JSON.parse(message.Body);

  logger.info(`Processing message [noteId=${noteId}]`);
  try {
    const note = await TestSessionNote.findById(noteId);
    const testSession = await TestSession.findById(note.test_session_id);
    logger.info(`Downloading video [key=${testSession.video_key}]`);

    const isProcessing = true;
    const interval = createInterval(500, startDateTime, message, isProcessing);
    await sleep(20000);
    clearInterval(interval);
    logger.info(`Finished processing message [noteId=${noteId}]`);
  } catch (ex) {
    await TestSessionNote.update(noteId, { status: 'transcribe_error' });
    logger.error(`Error processing message [noteId=${noteId}]`, ex);
  }
};
```

I know that if i create a var test = setInterval(() => {console.log('blabla')}, 500) and call clearInterval(test) it works, but i don't know how can i do this calling a function

Comment: You are not returning anything from `createInterval`. Use `return setInterval(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to return from **createInterval** function the **intervalId** and after that it should work.

Can you check what value has your intervalId right now, with your current implementation?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

"The returned intervalID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval(); this value can be passed to clearInterval() to cancel the interval."